# I keep getting errors when trying to deploy smart contracts to my blockchain using truffle

Tags: javascript, web3js, truffle, quorum, consensys-truffle

I have a set of smart contracts that I have compiled and deployed to rinkeby test network. I now need to deploy the to a private goquorum blockchain that runs on the IBFT consensus. The blockchain was built with quorum-wizard. It starts when I run ./start.sh

when I'm in the root of my truffle project I run sudo truffle deploy --reset --network quorum
I get the following error.

```
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.


/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:42
        return new Error(message);
               ^
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:42:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:92:32)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request-event-target.ts:44:13)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:219:8)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:379:8)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:266:37)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:493:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
    at PollingBlockTracker._performSync (/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/eth-block-tracker/src/polling.js:51:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

This is my truffle-config.js

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const mnemonic = "not my real mn emon ic words this is pl cfff was";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
  rinkeby: {
    provider: function() {
      return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/2342342342344345344343434");
    },
    network_id: '*',
    timeoutBlocks: 100000,
    networkCheckTimeout:2000000
  },
// https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/distributed-ledger-support/working-with-quorum
   quorum: {
    provider: function() {
      return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "http://127.0.0.1:21000/");
    },
    network_id: '*',
    type: "quorum",
    timeoutBlocks: 1000000,
    networkCheckTimeout:20000000
  }
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.5.0",
      settings: {
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true, // Default: false
          runs: 1000     // Default: 200
        },
        evmVersion: "homestead"  // Default: "byzantium"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I am using

Node v14.16.1

Ubuntu 18.04 (64 Bit)

Quorum 21.1.0

Web3.js v1.3.5

Truffle v5.3.4 (core: 5.3.4)

solidity v0.5.0

Comment: Are u missing host and port in the config?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67426600/smart-contracts-wont-deploy-to-a-goquorum-blockchain/67430998

Comment: its completely different . I am showing output from nmap and the truffle config is diferent

Comment: obviously not the same question

Comment: Yes, on the other thread you have more information like the output and nmap, and the truffle config.
But it's the same error and the steps you take to produce it are the same, right?
If so, you should delete this question and allow folks to respond on the other thread.