# Smart contracts won't deploy to a goQuorum blockchain

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js, truffle, quorum

I installed goQuorum with quorum-wizard with 4 quorum nodes and 4 tessera nodes on IBFT. When I start the network with "./start.sh" I get

```
Starting Quorum network...

Waiting until all Tessera nodes are running...
Waiting until all Tessera nodes are running...
All Tessera nodes started
Starting Quorum nodes
Successfully started Quorum network.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Tessera Node 1 public key:
BULeR8JyUWhiuuCMU/HLA0Q5pzkYT+cHII3ZKBey3Bo=

Tessera Node 2 public key:
QfeDAys9MPDs2XHExtc84jKGHxZg/aj52DTh0vtA3Xc=

Tessera Node 3 public key:
1iTZde/ndBHvzhcl7V68x44Vx7pl8nwx9LqnM/AfJUg=

Tessera Node 4 public key:
oNspPPgszVUFw0qmGFfWwh1uxVUXgvBxleXORHj07g8=

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

when I run "nmap -p 21000-21100" I get

21000/tcp open  irtrans
21001/tcp open  unknown
21002/tcp open  unknown
21003/tcp open  unknown

This is my truffle-config.js

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const mnemonic = "not my real mn mon ic num phrase dum get l gg";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
rinkeby: {
    provider: function() {
      return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/"+mnemonic);
    },
    network_id: '*',
    timeoutBlocks: 100000,
    networkCheckTimeout:2000000
  },
  quorum: {
    provider: function() {
      return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "http://127.0.0.1:21000/", chainId=10);
    },
    network_id: '*',
    type: 'quorum',
    timeoutBlocks: 100000,
    networkCheckTimeout:2000000
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.5.0",
      settings: {
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true, // Default: false
          runs: 1000     // Default: 200
        },
        evmVersion: "homestead"  // Default: "byzantium"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

When I cd in to the directory with the truffle-config.js and I run truffle deploy --reset --network quorum to compile my smart contracts I get the following error.

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.


/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:42
        return new Error(message);
               ^
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:42:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:92:32)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request-event-target.ts:44:13)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:219:8)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:379:8)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:266:37)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:493:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
    at PollingBlockTracker._performSync (/root/dapp1/Dapp/node_modules/eth-block-tracker/src/polling.js:51:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I can deploy the smart contracts to rinkeby test net within this environment but I can't get smart contracts to deploy to quorum

I am using

- Node v14.16.1
- Ubuntu 18.04 (64 Bit)
- Quorum 21.1.0
- Web3.js v1.3.5
- Truffle v5.3.4 (core: 5.3.4)
- solidity v0.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I've not used truffle with `HDWalletProvider`, which I believe is from an older version of Truffle. I'm not certain that will set up the node connection.

We would normally set up the configuration like the following in the `quorum: {}` section:

```
    host: "localhost",
    port: 22001,
    type: "quorum"
```

I would suggest using that and see if it works.

Take a look at the truffle docs for working with quorum: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/distributed-ledger-support/working-with-quorum

Answer (score 0):

Did you change from the default ports in the quorum-wizard?

The default for the node 1 RPC is 22000, the 21000 range is for p2p networking.

I would set the host and port per Satpal's answer above, as in the hdwallet documentation [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider).

Comment: Please avoid asking questions in your answer. If you need additional input from OP, use comments section.